# JQuery: show() and hide() targeting more than one div doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to achive here is to target a couple of divs to show or hide depanding on what the val is. In this case it doesn't work, when I have only one div target it works, but only for 1 of the to hide not two of them. I am not really sure if I can target multiple divs ?

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#state").change(function() {
            // foo is the id of the other select box 
            if ($(this).val() == "twoChoices") {
                $("#foo", "#foo1", "#foo2", "#foo3").show();
            }else{
                $("#foo", "#foo1", "#foo2", "#foo3").hide();
            } 
        });



 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="Choice" class="col-sm-8 control-label">How many?</label>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
 <select id="state" class="form-control">
   <option value="oneChoice">1</option>
   <option value="twoChoices">2</option>
 </select>
</div>
</div>

 <div id="foo" class="form-group">
    <label for="Choice" class="col-sm-8 control-label">First to be</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <select id="mixOrSingle" class="form-control">
    <option value="mix">Mix</option>
    <option value="single">Single</option>
      </select>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div id="foo2" class="form-group">
   <label for="Choice" class="col-sm-8 control-label">Second to be</label>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
     <select id="mixOrSingle" class="form-control">
   <option value="mix">Mix</option>
       <option value="single">Single</option>
</select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because, the way you have used the [`multiple-selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) is wrong.

Try,

```
 $("#foo,#foo1,#foo2,#foo3").show();
```

Full code,

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $("#state").change(function() {
       $("#foo,#foo1,#foo2,#foo3").toggle($(this).val() == "twoChoices");
    });
 });
```

Comment: Also, target option value not select.

Comment: Select's value is not but its option value is.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Hey, mate another thing when I see the box "
How Many" and i have to click on it and select 2 and the go back to 1 in order to hide. I put the <option selected value=1">1</option> and it's still not fixing it. Any ideas ?

Comment: @user3311769 what is the use of the double quote here..? `<option selected value=1">1</option>`   especially in `value=1"`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy nothing sorry my mistake: <option value="oneChoice" id="1" selected="selected">1</option>  this doesn't work and I still need to change to the second option and then go back to the 1st option in order the fileds to hide

Comment: @user3311769 you are expecting the hiding process to be happened in the initial stage itself.. But that wont happen unless the user is interacting with that select box. If you want to happen it for sure, just write css according to that.. meaning set `display:none` to the elements which needs to be hidden initially..

Answer (score 0):

You might be better using classes too, to keep this cleaner and easier to maintain ?

Say html:

```
<div id="foo" class="form-group twoChoice"></div>
<div id="foo1" class="form-group twoChoice"></div>
<div id="foo2" class="form-group twoChoice"></div>
```

and JS

```
$("#state").change(function() {
   $("."+$(this).val()).toggle();
   /* or what ever logic */
});
```

---

Your current example makes no sense, as, whatever the value, it hides the same elements, but I guess that's just to show the problem. The key would be to target the class rather than all those chained id's.

---

Update, forgot to say. A nice convention too is to name those classes more verbose, so easier to see what is happening in 12 months time :)

eg

```
<div id="foo" class="form-group js-hiddenBy_twoChoice"></div>
<div id="foo1" class="form-group js-hiddenBy_twoChoice"></div>
<div id="foo2" class="form-group js-hiddenBy_twoChoice"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#state").change(function() {
   $(".js-hiddenBy_"+$(this).val()).hide();
});
```